# PlayMode tests stopping by default if errors are logged in scripts

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, logging

Empirically, I can see that Unity stops running a PlayMode test if any error log is created programmatically when a script calls [`Debug.LogError`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogError.html).

This is a problem for me because I would like PlayMode tests to only stop on assertion failures.

Is there any way to tell Unity not to stop the current PlayMode test if an error is logged?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disable *Error Pause* on the Console tab. This should prevent `Debug.LogError` from pausing your Game.

[image]

---

If this test is not done in the Editor then it will fail. To prevent that, immediately call `LogAssert.Expect` after `Debug.LogError` to prevent Unity from stopping or the test from failing when `Debug.LogError` is called.

```
Debug.LogError("Your Error");

LogAssert.Expect(LogType.Error, "Your Error");
```

---

*Edit*:

In *Unity 2017* and above, you can now use `LogAssert.ignoreFailingMessages` to accomplish that by setting it to true. You can still use the answer above for older Unity version.

```
LogAssert.ignoreFailingMessages = true;
```

Comment: Expecting it works, but is this the only way? There is no global way to tell Unity to expect all error logs?

Comment: Yup. Thar's the only way according to the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html)

Comment: You can easily write a wrapper or a function for this that calls both `Debug.Log` then `LogAssert.Expect`

Comment: It can be done globally since 2017.1, see [LogAssert-ignoreFailingMessages](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TestTools.LogAssert-ignoreFailingMessages.html)

Comment: @Jethro Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 4):

To allow all Error messages you can set [LogAssert.ignoreFailingMessages](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TestTools.LogAssert-ignoreFailingMessages.html) to true.